# How to get input radio button values in javascript or ajax and show/hide a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with the following input buttons:

```
<input type="radio" value="2" id="order_status"> Review
<input type="radio" value="1" id="order_status"> Accept
<input type="radio" value="2" id="order_status"> Decline
<input type="radio" value="3" id="order_status"> Refund


<textarea id="remarks"> </textarea>
<input type ="button" value="Update" id="updateBtn" name="updateBtn"onclick="submitForm2()">
```

What I want to do here is to get the value of radio button and if it is 2 textarea (remark) should not be empty. So the update button should not be submit-able,  Else if the value of radio button is 0 or 1, the remark may or may not be empty, the submit button should also work... 
How to do it, Can anyone explain it please...

```
function submitForm2()
{
var remarkVal = $("#remarks").val();
var remark = $("#remarks").val().length;
var order_status = $('form input:checked').attr('value');

if(order_status== 2 || order_status == 3){
    if(remark < 15){
    //alert("Please Fill The Remarks Field");
    return false;
alert(remarkA);
}
else if(remark > 15){
    return true;
}
else 
{

    $.ajax({
      url:"orderStatusUpdate.php",  
      type:"GET",
    //  data:"order_status="+order_status+"&id="+<?php echo $id; ?>+"&uid="+<?php echo $uid;?>, <?php echo $edited_by;?>

     data:"order_status="+order_status+"&remarks="+remarkVal+"&id="+<?php echo $id; ?>+"&uid="+<?php echo $uid;?>, <?php echo $edited_by;?>

      success:function(content) {
      history.go(1);
      }
   });
}
}
```

Comment: **ID SHOULD BE UNIQUE**, use `name` instead of ID.

Comment: `What I want to do here` .... have you tried something ... or just want us to write code for you.

Comment: Or don't use `id` at all if you are not referring it anywhere..

Comment: this works fine for me. I am checking against the value of the radio button....

Comment: Im able to get the value of radio in this way : I am using : " var order_status = $('form input:checked').attr('value'); "

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/f6zvbsqs/

Comment: Dear – Kartikeya Khosla Khosla I have update my question, Please have a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head> 
    <body>
       <input type="radio" value="2"> Review
        <input type="radio" value="1"> Accept
        <input type="radio" value="2"> Decline
        <input type="radio" value="3"> Refund
        <textarea id="remarks"> </textarea>
        <input type ="button" value="Update" id="updateBtn" name="updateBtn"onclick="submitForm2()">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm2()
        {
            var remarkVal = $("#remarks").val();
            var remark = $("#remarks").val().length;
            var order_status = $('input:checked').val();

            if(order_status== 2 || order_status == 3){
                if(remark < 15 || remark == ''){
                    alert("Please Fill The Remarks Field");
                    return false;
                } else if(remark > 15){
                    return true;
                }
           } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"orderStatusUpdate.php",
                    type:"GET",
                    data:"order_status="+order_status+"&remarks="+remarkVal+"&id="+'<?php echo $id; ?>'+"&uid="+'<?php echo $uid;?>'+'<?php echo $edited_by;?>',
                    success:function(content) {
                        history.go(1);
                    }
               });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you! :)

Comment: Yess Great, But the last else part does not work.... Dont know what is wrong ... It is fine when value = 2 or 3 but, does not work when the radio button's value is 1 or 2. Pressing the update button does nothing....

Comment: Yahoooooo... You are right, I got it.  #darkvirus24 Thanks YOu Soooo Much and Live Long. You made My Day Great......   darkvirus24 You are great... Stay Blessed